# Excel Formula for Cell References

Tags: excel-formula

I have built a spreadsheet for stock ordering purposes, and I have a simply formula in Row 21 column U, that says IF(AC22="Delivery","Order",""). This is because the lead time is 8 months, and so I have linked it to the cell 8 months ahead. I have a number of different products with different lead times, so I have tried to find a way to have a cell that tells the formula how far ahead to look for the delivery so that I can easily update it for the different products.

[Stock Ordering Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lu4Z.jpg)

Any advice would be gratefully received.
Graham

Comment: How is the lead time calculated or the specific lead time value in a different column?

Comment: The lead time is currently just written in a cell as either 4 months or 8 months depending on the product. The cell AC22 that shows Delivery is based on a formula when the stock on hand the month before drops below 100 days. This then says tells us the delivery is needed that month and my current formula tells me when to order. But looking for a quick way of updating the formula if the lead time changes, rather than relinking the cell for each product, if that makes sense

Comment: What specific cell is the lead time in?

Comment: At the moment it is in A8

Comment: hi @GClark, could you provide an outline of the excel sheet structure and a minimum example to replicate the question..?

Comment: Hi Bagus, I think I have managed to add a picture to the original post. Hopefully this will help to show the layout.